# How to assign keyboard shortcuts to already opened windows

Tags: shortcuts, shortcut-keys

Let's say I have opened four Calc windows, two Nautilus windows and, say, Celestia. How can I register keyboard shortcuts to switch between them with one key-combo?

Comment: Well there's Alt+Tab shortcut for switching windows if that's what you need

Comment: No, with Alt+Tab I can only cycle through windows. I want to switch right to specific window instantly.

Comment: Oh. Actually, if you cycle with Alt+Tab, and pause for a second over LibreOffice for example, it will give you a choice of which document you want to see. Also right clicking on the LibreOffice in the launcher will give you option of which open document to see. As far as short-cuts there isn't anything I've heard of. But that how I switch between multiple instances of the program open. Right clicking is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch between different programs.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> will switch between different programs, according to their order on the Launcher.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (key below esc) will switch between different windows of the same program.